# Jenkins builds using Bitbucket Server Integration Plugin

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, webhooks, bitbucket-server

I am able to trigger builds in Jenkins via BitBucket Server Integration plugin which automatically sets a webhook on BitBucket.

I see build getting triggered when a pull request is raised.
However, I am noticing that when a build is running on Jenkins and if the pull request gets updated then I don't see next build getting queued in Jenkins.
Build does get executed when the current build completes for the updated ref but why don't I see it getting queued?
Same behavior is seen if there are multiple pull-requests.

Ideally, pull requests should be able to be built concurrently.

I do have below setting in Jenkins to trigger parallel builds. Not sure, what I am missing here

[image]

[image]

I do see payload being sent from Bitbucket when Pull request is updated.

And on Jenkins log I found an error:

```
INFO com.atlassian.bitbucket.jenkins.internal.http.HttpRequestExecutorImpl handleError
Bitbucket - Path not found
```

If path was not found then I can understand there is some configuration issue on my end but once the current build completes it does trigger another build.

Problem is:

1. Why can't I build multiple pull request in parallel using BitBucket Server Integration Plugin?
2. If Jenkins does queue the build internally then why doesn't it show on the Jenkins UI?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue before.
Basically what I understand is that Jenkins cannot differentiate the events that are coming from Bitbucket webhook. You basically need a differentiator.

What I did is, make my web-hook listener job parameterised based on the payload input.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Here the most important thing for me was to add the date-time, because I have many requests coming at almost same time from bitbucket.

Hopefully this will help in your setup.